# delete space and line breaks inside anchor tags present in a string collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

From last couple of days i have been trying to solve this problem as i have a string collection which contain many anchor tags i want to pick those anchor tags which is coming under specific comment section now what i have done is, i broke the whole string collection by "\n".And i got an array collection and i read the array and pick anchor tags, Its running smoothly but for some string collection its creating a problem like i found some anchor tags have space and line breaks inside it like shown below.

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.home.test.com/test/redirector.jspx?                   
action=ref&cname=test_EDITORIAL&ckey     =2421515&cc=US&lc=eng&cmpid=MA43304BL"      
style="font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;color:        
                                          #0085d5">application note</a>
```

as i broke the whole string collection by "\n" so the above anchor tag is now coming in two separate arrays so its not finding the closing anchor tag. 
i want to make this anchor tag like without space and line breaks inside it like shown below...

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.home.test.com/test/redirector.jspx?                   
action=ref&cname=test_EDITORIAL&ckey=2421515&cc=US&lc=eng&cmpid=MA43304BL"      
style="font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;color:#0085d5">application note</a>
```

Is there is any way to delete space and line breaks inside the anchor tag and again add it to string collection so that i can read the anchor tags and pick it up.You can't rely on parent or child elements as its a string collection.

Comment: Is breaking the string collection by "\n" provided it is not prefaced with ":" an option?

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle example? It's hard to understand.

Comment: @lugia i think i explained the question in well mannered way...:)

Comment: @win Might just be me, but are you trying to remove all whitespace within the string or?

Comment: @helpful i split the string collection like this                    var lines = filteredText.split("\n"); filteredText is my string collection and lines contain arrays.

Comment: @lugia  i split the string collection like this                     var lines = filteredText.split("\n"); Now filteredText is my string collection and lines contain arrays.

Comment: @lugia yes i want to remove the space and line breaks inside the anchor tags.

Comment: Try my answer, it works with a test string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$("a").each(function (i, el) {
    var r = /\s+|\r+|\n+|\t+/g;
    $(el).eq(i).attr({
        "href": $(el).attr("href").replace(r, ""),
        "style": $(el).attr("style").replace(r, "")
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/mt8YU/

Comment: if i want to delete whitespace and linebrek inside href only then the above code will work or not....If not then pls help..:)

Comment: @win If requirement for only href attribute, can remove style property within .attr(). Please check console at jsfiddle link to view result of piece ? Is requirement for href attribute, only, or style attribute as well ? See updated post. Thanks –

Answer (score 0):

try to strip string with `.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
var value = $("a").attr('href');
var strip = value.replace(/ /g, '');
$( "a" ).attr( "href", strip );
```

Here is a sample [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDY3f/).

Answer (score 0):

Try looping through and fixing the string as a whole:

```
var inside = 0
for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
    if(string.charAt(i) == '<' || (string.charAt(i) == '"' && inside != 2)) inside++;
    else if(string.charAt(i) == '>' || (string.charAt(i) == '"' && inside == 2)) inside--;
    if((string.charAt(i) == '\n' || string.charAt(i) == ' ') && inside == 2){
        string = string.substr(0, i) + string.substr(i + 1);
        i--;
    }
}
```

Comment: $(filteredText).find('a').each(function () { //filteredText   is my string collection.----
           var c = this.href;
           var l = c.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
           alert(ll);                                              //in alert i should get the urls without space and line breks but iam not getting.Do u have any idea about this.           
                    })